# How to export fbx with terragen 3

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, 3d-model

I have already download and create terrain by **terragen 3** on my **mac and pc** .
when i export object i can't find any object on my unity3d  that i used pc want to export again, however i can't find export button on pc .

i have aleady tried:
1:export fbx by  File->export fbx Scene

like this [image]

my question is :

1: how to export fbx format on terragen3 ?

2: how to export project on terragen3?

3: unity3d can use ter3 obj ? if can use it how should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

The Export FBX option on the File menu exports Light and Camera position and animation data into FBX, it does not export geometry. If you want to export terrain geometry into FBX, use the Micro Exporter, documentation and instructions here: 
http://www.planetside.co.uk/wiki/index.php?title=Micro_Exporter

Comment: i have already try micro exporter. but still not to export anything . just had light and camera

Comment: That sounds like the FBX export. The micro exporter does not export either of those (lights/camera). Did you follow the 4 step instructions in the link above? Once you setup your micro exporter, you must *render* the scene to output the geometry. You do *not* use any of the "FBX Export" options on the File menu.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me fine.

To make rendertimes as short as possible during exporting the terrain temporarily disable athmosphere, clouds and GI, uncheck "cast shadows" of the sun. If you want nothing but the terrain, uncheck all objects too.

Go to the render tab, under "sequence/Output" drop down menu go to the Micro exporter, check it and hit "create new micro handler". Important: choose "Micro exporter", not LWO micro exporter!

Go to this micro exporter, set your farthest distance (it's set to a very high value by default). You have to test that. You can start with a value of 10000. That's going to be how far away the border of your exported terrain will be.

Under filename write "your filename.obj". Hit Render. Done.

This way you have the portion of your terrain your camera can see.

Comment: so to actually export the geometry you have to render the image or what do you mean with hit render?